# Insert data to database using Excel VBA is not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, sql-server, sql

I have a macro that will upload data from multiple workbooks to the database. Table will differs based on what type of value/data being inserted. I have there tables. I can insert value in the first table just fine, but when it comes to second table, there's no value inserted, and im using the the exact same code as the first one but with different variables.

```
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim connection, insertData As String

connection = "Provider=; Database= Database; Integrated Security=SSPI;"

'open connection
 conn.Open connection

insertData = "INSERT INTO Table2 ([Name], [AScore], [BScore], [CScore], [DScore], [EScore], [FScore]) " & _
             " VALUES ('" & _
             SummWb.Sheets("Sheet 2").Cells(13, "I").Value & "' , '" & _
             SummWb.Sheets("Sheet 2").Cells(11, "J").Value & "' , '" & _
             SummWb.Sheets("Sheet 2").Cells(6, "J").Value & "' , '" & _
             SummWb.Sheets("Sheet 2").Cells(7, "J").Value & "' , '" & _
             SummWb.Sheets("Sheet 2").Cells(3, "J").Value & "' , '" & _
             SummWb.Sheets("Sheet 2").Cells(9, "J").Value & "' , '" & _
             SummWb.Sheets("Sheet 2").Cells(10, "J").Value & "')"
conn.Execute insertData
conn.close
```

I've tried to see if my code is wrong, and I also tried to drop the table and create a new table, and also using a new workbook to test the code, but the result is still the same. Can you please help to see what is wrong with my code? I am using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: What version of SQL server.. Is the code about the second table?

Comment: Hi @Dave its 2010 version and yes the code is for second table

Comment: I don't think we could solve it for you, you need to debug your code and find what's the issue. try to step your code (F8) until the line "insertData = ..." then insert your expression prededed by a `?` into watch window (e.g. `? "INSERT INTO Table2...`) and press Enter. That will show you how VBA compose the query string. Check whether it's correct. Also try to run it in SQL Server Management Studio. I suppose there will be issue related to data types (e.g. you put a number within `'`s when it shouldn't be.

Comment: Hi @MátéJuhász after a lot of try and error, the last resort for me was to type again, everything from the beginning, and somehow, it miraculously works. Thanks for your tips! Will use it in the future.

Comment: great it's solved! You can compare your current code with the one in the question, so you might learn what was the issue and will be easier to avoid it in the future. (You can even post the solution as an answer).

Comment: Glad you solved it.  Maybe "Sheet2" vs your "Sheet 2" ?